# conditional handling of update sql script depending on input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am new to SQL and using Oracle 11. I need to write a sql script which uses different update command based on whether the input param is null or not null.

I need something like this

['&' followed by the parameter name is the way i see parameters being used in other such
script for our project]

```
IF &PRG_ID IS NULL
   UPDATE PROGRAM_TABLE P SET HANDLED_IND = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM HANDLED_PROGRAM H WHERE H.PROGRAM_ID = P.PROGRAM_ID);
ELSE
   UPDATE PROGRAM_TABLE P SET HANDLED_IND = 'Y' WHERE 
     P.PROGRAM_ID = &PRG_ID AND EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM HANDLED_PROGRAM H WHERE H.PROGRAM_ID = P.PROGRAM_ID);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (is not tested):

```
   UPDATE PROGRAM_TABLE P SET HANDLED_IND = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM HANDLED_PROGRAM H WHERE H.PROGRAM_ID = P.PROGRAM_ID)
      AND (&PRG_ID IS NULL OR P.PROGRAM_ID = &PRG_ID);
```

But take into account this change may lead to the performance degradation for the case when PRG_ID has definite value.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, would using 2 queries be justified taking in consideration the performance, something like        

UPDATE PROGRAM_TABLE P SET HANDLED_IND = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1 FROM HANDLED_PROGRAM H WHERE H.PROGRAM_ID =            P.PROGRAM_ID)
          AND (&PRG_ID IS NULL);


UPDATE PROGRAM_TABLE P SET HANDLED_IND = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1 FROM HANDLED_PROGRAM H WHERE H.PROGRAM_ID = P.PROGRAM_ID)
          AND &PRG_ID IS NOT NULL   AND P.PROGRAM_ID = &PRG_ID;

Comment: Not really. If you experience performance problems due to (&PRG_ID IS NULL OR P.PROGRAM_ID = &PRG_ID) I would stay with your original code - if you use update statement inside PL/SQL this looks well.